# Why is my response always http 400 status code

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm learning Node.js and I'm working on a sample app. I've a question why is that I always receive http 400 even if it is a successful response.

```
    abcRoutes.get('/fetch', function (req, res) {
     abc.getInfo(req,(err,response) =>{
       if(err){
         res.status(400).send(err);
       }else{
         res.status(200).send(response);
       }
     })
    });



       var getInfo = (req, callBack) => {

        ***some processing***
            if (err) {
                callBack(err);
            } else {
                callBack(result);
            }
        });
        client.close();
    }
})
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```js
var getInfo = (req, callBack) => {
  //* **some processing***
  if (err) {
    callBack(err)
  } else {
    callBack(null, result) <---
  }
}
```

Using callback pattern you need to keep in mind that the first argument is always an error.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the first argument (`err`) to `null` on success:

```
if (err) {
  callBack(err);
}
else {
  callBack(null, result);
}
```